# teamcity and xunit 2.0

Tags: teamcity, xunit, xunit2, teamcity-9.1

I am trying to get teamcity 9.1.1 to run an xunit 2.0 tests that where made int visual studio 2015.

Here is what i have done:

1. downloaded the zip
   (https://github.com/carlpett/xUnit-TeamCity/releases/tag/1.0 and
   https://github.com/rhysgodfrey/team-city-xunit-meta-runner/releases
   but neither are showing)
2. Under Administration -> Plugins, clicked the Upload plugin zip.
3. restarted the server.

My problem is that i cannot see the Plugin in the list under external plugin nor can i find the build runner when i go to add a step.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm doing this and have the exact same issue as you

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i uploaded the zip file without the extension.
Simple upload it again with .zip